# Ramsey's original proof of Ramsey's theorem reference

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, reference-request

Does anyone have a reference for Ramsey's original proof of Ramsey's theorem (ie the paper he published). Wikipedia references link to [this paper](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1112/plms/s2-30.1.264) but its only about logic, there is no mention of graphs. I've been reading it and looking for something equivalent but its a bit hard to digest, I don't think its in there.

Comment: It's there, just not in the terminology you're used to. Theorem A is the infinite Ramsey theorem and theorem B is the finite Ramsey theorem, which is probably what you're looking for. If you will tellme the exact formulation of the version of Ramsey's theorem that you want, I could try to explain how to derive it from Ramsey;s theorem B.

Comment: By the way, Ramsey did not write many papers (he died young), and I'm pretty sure that paper "On a Problem of Formal Logic" is the one and only place he wrote about "Ramsey's theorem".

Comment: Just set $r=2$ in Ramsey's Theorem B.

Comment: As far as I remember, Ramsey himself was not interested in graphs at all, so you will probably indeed not find any applications of his theorem to graphs in his own papers. He just proved it for the implications in logic.